# Sort Core Data attributes both by Date and Character

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to search my core data, by default it searches title attribute but I need to sort results by `date` as well.

My code searches `title` attribute but how can I make two `predicates` and connect them with the `context` ?

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    //Load data from Core Data
    let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    context =  appDel.managedObjectContext

    do {

        request =  NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
        let sort:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"title", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@", prospectiveText)
        request.predicate = searchPredicate
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        animateTableCell()


    } catch {

        print("ERROR")
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear whether you're interesting in *selection* or *sorting*.  Predicates are used to determine which records to select, and sort descriptors are used to sort the results.

For sorting, `request.sortDescriptors` is an array of descriptors.  So you can have multiple descriptors, for example:

```
let sort:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"title", ascending: true)
let sort2:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"date", ascending: false)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort, sort2]
```

should sort by ascending title, then descending date (i.e. those items with the same title should be in descending order by date).